# Docker container network bridge

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, default

i am using a Raspberry PI as a VPN network gateway to route all my traffic into it.
so on the PI i want to set up a docker container.
The appliations in the docker container should not route through the vpn tunnel.
So can i use a network bridge to assign a IP address from the local DHCP server wich provide another default route ?
I see there is an option called --net host 
Or what should i do ?

Thanks

Best Regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, attach the containers to the `host` network.
Use `--network host` with `docker run` and your container will be connected to your RPI's network and will see all its interfaces.

Then you can fiddle with VPN.